# Why do I get a Linker error on "-reexport_framework" while building dependencies on iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, xcode6, soundcloud

I am following the instructions to test SoundCloud APIs on iOS. I added the neessary projects and the settings. But I get this error when I build the project. Can someone please decipher the error message?

Thanks!

[image]

Reference:https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart#installation

Comment: did my answer help?  If so, please mark it as accepted.  If not, please provide more information so I can try to help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's an architecture issue with your project and that framework.  I think that sample project from SoundCloud is pretty old.  Try setting `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO` under Targets -> Your App -> Build Settings -> Architectures.

EDIT: I figured out some of the things you did wrong.  Your project is set up a little weird.  You don't have the correct Target Dependencies and binaries in Link Binaries With Libraries.  Check the image below of what yours should look like:

[image: Xcode]

I followed the instructions and created a sample project that builds.  Feel free to check it out:

http://lieberman.nyc/sample_soundcloud_project_for_relatively_slow_on_stackoverflow.zip

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Unfortunately that didnt help. : ( https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81597211/TestS.zip

Comment: Hi, haven't had a lot of time to look into this but I'm still thinking about it.  The fundamental issue is a problem with the OAuth2Client framework not supporting certain architectures.  Will continue to look into this and report back as time allows.

Comment: @unj2 I've edited my answer to provide some more information.  I've also attached a sample project if you're still having trouble.

Comment: The sample project worked awesome!!! You are incredible!! Was the problem with the OAuth2Client? What changes did you have to make? Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't know, I just created a new project and followed the instructions on the SoundCloud documentation page.  You may have forgotten to link some of the libraries in the "Link Binary with Libraries" section.  Glad I was able to help.